# Create a "bridge" between a Wireguard interface and a public IP on a remote host

Tags: linux, networking, cloud

I have "powerful" computers at home, with a gigabit internet connection and lots of beautiful storage, but I can only get one single public IP.

I would like to run my own public services, but I do not want to expose my private public IP at home and I do not want to have to rent computers when I have perfectly good ones at home.

What I want to do, is to get a cheap cloud VM that offers multiple IPs and use that VM to setup one Wireguard interface per home server and then link them, so that I can use the public IP in the cloud as if it was a public IP at home.

I understand you can't bridge a layer 3 VPN to a layer 2 interface, but that's the best way I know how to put it. Everything that is sent out of my wg0 at home, goes out on the public IP in the cloud and vice versa.

How do I do this? Thanks for helping. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can just *route* the public addresses across the VPN tunnel into your home system – they are not actually bound to the VPS somehow – and assign them directly to your home servers, instead of assigning them to the VPS. (There's not really any "bridging" of any form, it's still well within the VPN's basic function of routing IP packets.)

```
ip route add 83.171.257.5 dev wg0
```

(You'll also need to update WireGuard "AllowedIPs" or define OpenVPN "iroute".)

Once the addresses are routed to your home network, your home VPN endpoint also needs to know where to route them (either directly to your LAN interface, or via your servers' LAN addresses), and eventually they can be assigned to the servers' interfaces.

Depending on datacenter, the additional IPs may be either routed to the VPS's "primary" IP address, in which case you don't need to do anything special (just don't assign them to the VPS), or they may be "on-link", in which case the VPS needs to run *proxy ARP* and continue answering the datacenter gateway's ARP queries despite no longer having the addresses.

(Running a packet capture on the server's main Ethernet interface is one way to find out which kind it is. If you see ARP requests for the additional IPs, well, something has to answer them – it means the addresses are on-link and you'll need to enable Proxy ARP on the VPS. Either the kernel's built-in proxy-ARP system or the 'parpd' daemon can be used for that purpose.)

---

*As an alternative method:*

Most basic VPN configurations already include SNAT (aka masquerading) so that packets from VPN clients will be assigned the VPN server's IP address, in the same way that packets leaving your home router are assigned the router's IP address.

You can easily extend this to multiple IP addresses by just tweaking the firewall rules that are added to implement SNAT. For example, instead of just having one rule that matches everything, you would have multiple rules that each additionally use `-s` or `ip saddr` to match one of your servers' LAN addresses.

```
chain postrouting {
    ip saddr 10.147.0.5    snat to 83.171.257.5
    ip saddr 10.147.0.6    snat to 83.171.257.6
    ip saddr 10.147.0.0/24 snat to 83.171.257.2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that: https://github.com/mochman/Bypass_CGNAT/wiki

You can do that easy and for free using oracle free tier and automated script:
https://github.com/mochman/Bypass_CGNAT/wiki/Oracle-Cloud-(Automatic-Installer-Script)

Comment: Welcome to SU. Please view the [guidelines for answers](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer). While referring to external resources is good, your answer should stand on its own even if the external resource disappeared. Please check the [Tour](https://superuser.com/tour), Asking and Answering -sections in the [Help](https://superuser.com/help) and some older questions with [accepted answers](https://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer) to learn how SE sites work.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1180333)